# Is it possible to implement an in-place multiplication quantum circuit?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, circuit-construction, arithmetic

How can a reversible multiplication quantum circuit be implemented? By "reversible" I mean one that performs `a *= b` on the inputs a and b of the multiplication. In this case, it is reversible because the inverse operation `a /= b` exists. I believe the multiplication requires some ancilla bits, but it needs to be able to be reset to |0> by uncomputation after multiplication.

---

My explanation may have been insufficient, so I will write it in more detail. The multiplier circuit I am trying to build is one that calculates the product for input registers `a` and `b` and sets it in register `a`. Namely,

$|a\rangle|b\rangle \rightarrow |a\times b\rangle |b\rangle$

The necessary ancilla bits must be able to be set back to $|0\rangle$  by uncomputation.

$|a\rangle|b\rangle|00\dots0\rangle_a \rightarrow |a\times b\rangle |b\rangle|00\dots0\rangle_a$

Thank you in advance for your comments and advice.

Comment: This may not be the full state-of-the-art, but if you look at the relevant parts of Appendix A and Appendix B of this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.12445 you will have an explanation of a nice reversible implementation of multiplication on a quantum computer.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! If I understand correctly, the implementation described in that paper requires a separate register to output the product. The circuit I want to know is `a *= b` i.e. the product of `a * b` is set to `a` (my explanation was lacking, sorry). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, any classical computation can be turned into a reversible computation using enough ancilla bits. This is also true for the quantum case.

Specifically, the $AND$ gate can be built using the $CCNOT$ (Toffoli) gate. Adding the $NOT$ gate, which is already reversible, and we have a (classical) universal set of gates using $NAND$.

Comment: Thank you! I added a description to my question, and I can't come up with a good digital circuit for a case like $|a\rangle|b\rangle \rightarrow |a\times b\rangle|b\rangle$ where the product is output to the input register.